# Errors not being detected in Flash Builder 4

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I'm relatively new to Flash Builder 4 and Flex but am familiar with programming IDEs and in particular Visual Studio and .NET

As with most IDEs when you type something that is an error it will highlight it with the red cross or red underline, and this is what used to happen in Flash Builder 4 but for some reason now it does not work.

I can type any old garbage and hit save, which forces the build (I have build automatically selected) and no error shows on the line, or in the Problems panel. It will allow me to run the application too.

Anybody have any idea what i have done to stop this from working?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which version of Flash Builder?  Which version of the Flex SDK?  Is the file your editing an ActionScript file?  An MXML file?  Or some other type of file?  Is the file your editing being used in the project? Something sounds amiss, especially if you aren't even getting runtime errors.  I'm just sure what.

Comment: Ok sorry about this. It turns out there is a difference between VS and FB4 that means that if your custom component isn't actually used anywhere then the compiler doesn't bother to check the code. Once i added the control to another element it popped up with a load of errors.

Comment: This 'feature' has been fixed in flash Builder 4.5 .  At least for library projects [and I assume main projects].  You should write up your solution as a formal answer and mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok So it was a simple case of the custom component I had created wasn't being used in any other component. In version 4 this would cause the component not to be compiled and therefore any errors in the component would not be recognised.

I haven't had a chance to upgrade to 4.5 yet to verify it is addressed in that version, but thank you for your responses